# Function to Avoid Variable Undefined

Tags: php, function, variables, undefined

I am trying to write a function to avoid getting variable undefined error. Right now, i have a code like this:

```
function check($str){
  if(isset($str)){
   $s = $str;
  } else {
   $s = "";
}
}

check($_GET['var']);
```

The get var is not set. I am getting a variable undefined error on my screen. How do i alter my function to not throw this error and just return "" if it is not set? I don't want to have to code 100 if statements to avoid getting variable undefined. Thanks.

Comment: You're not doing anything with `$s` once it's set. `$s` does not exist outside of the function, so you'll have to return the value.

Comment: Why not just do `$_GET['var'] ?? 'whatever you want as the default'`?

Comment: However, it's not going to get that far, because the key has to exist before you can pass it in. You might want to do something similar to [array_key_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

Answer (score 1):

We already have in PHP a construct to check that. It is called [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php). With it you can check whether a variable exists. If you would like to create it with some default values if it doesn't exist yet, we also have syntax for it. It's null-coalescing operator.

```
$_GET['var'] = $_GET['var'] ?? '';
// or since PHP 7.4 
$_GET['var'] ??= '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure if it is the right way of doing it, for the sake of providing an answer you can pass the variable by reference, this allows you to get away with passing undefined variables and check if it is set inside the function..

```
function check(&$str){
    if(!isset($str)){
        $str = "not set";
    }
}
check($_GET['var']);

echo $_GET['var'];
```